# Linq - Referencing a Child Table

Tags: linq, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I have a few tables I'm dealing with regarding a "Goals" application (screen grab is below). I'm using MVC 3, razor and linq.

I am using a model, goalsModel, to retrieve my data:

`public goals GetGoal(int id)
    {
    return qDB.goals.Single(g => g.goalID == id);
    }`

I'd like Activities to be available as well... where I could do something like:

`public goals GetGoalActivities(int id)
    {
    return qDB.ilpActivities.Where(g => g.goalID == id);
    }`

However this returns an error. The smart tags for don't show any columns available for ilpActivities. I've seen several methods of writing code in the controller where it's a linq query - but I'd really like to use the format above if possible for consistency.

Here's a link that I've been trying to follow that may do what I want. Keep in mind, however, I'll eventually be editing existing activities, creating new ones, and deleting activities. The link: http://geekswithblogs.net/michelotti/archive/2007/12/30/118076.aspx

[Edit]
I couldn't post an image as a new user. My tables consist of goalID as the primary key of goals and foreign key in ilpActivities. ilpActivities has a primary key of activityID.

[Update]

My tables look something like this (simplified to include relevant fields):
goals: goalID, goalName, goalDescr
ilpActivities: activityID, goalID, activityName

I have a dbml file: employeeDataClasses.dbml that was generated for me after dragging the tables in on design mode. It recognized ilpActivities as a child of goals

I have a goalsModel.cs file:

```
namespace ILP.Models
{
public class goalsModel
{
    #region services
    public interface IGoalsService
    {
        List<goals> GetAllGoals(string oprID);
        bool CreateGoal(goals poll);
        List<ilpGoalStatus> GetStatuses();
        goals GetGoal(int id);
        bool EditGoal(goals poll);
        List<ilpActivity> GetGoalActivities(goals goal);
    }

    public class AssetService : IGoalsService
    {
        private goalsDataClassesDataContext qDB;

        public AssetService()
        {
            qDB = new goalsDataClassesDataContext();
        }

        #region IGoalsService Members
            public List<ilpActivity> GetGoalActivities (goals goal) 
        {
            IEnumerable<ilpActivity> activities = from g in qDB.goals
                         join a in qDB.ilpActivities on g.goalID equals a.goalID
                         where a.goalID == goal.goalID
                         select a;

            return activities.ToList();
        }
```

In my controller:

```
namespace ILP.Controllers
{
public class HomeController : Controller
{

    private goalsModel.IGoalsService qService;

    public HomeController()
    {
        qService = new goalsModel.AssetService();
    }
        [Authorize]
    public ActionResult _CreateActivity(int goalID)
    {
        //var status = qService.GetStatuses();
        ViewBag.Status = new SelectList(qService.GetStatuses().ToList(), "goalStatusID", "goalStatus");
// not sure what to do here to get activity model in....
        return PartialView();
    }
```

In my create activity partialview I'm only getting access to the goals model:

```
@model ILP.Models.goals

<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-1.5.1.min.js")"     type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>

@using (Html.BeginForm()) {
@Html.ValidationSummary(true)
<fieldset>
    <legend>Create an Activity</legend>

    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.goalName)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.goalName)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.goalName)
    </div>
.... etc....
```

In my view I need to access activityName of ilpActivities - but the only options are coming from goals table.

Comment: What is the error.. is it exploding because the DataContext is dead by the time it tries to enumerate?

Comment: No - It doesn't "see" the contents of my child table (ilpActivities). So when I try to add form fields: @Html.Editorfor(a => a.ilpActivities.activityName)   -- the "activityName" doesn't appear in the smart tags

Comment: It appears that your ultimate question relates to your view.  To pass your child table and its attributes to your view, you need to pass the view a model which contains your child table in its structure.  Please post some detail about the structure of your tables, as well as about the structure of the model you want to pass to the view, as well as some more detailed code regarding your view.  It is much easier to advise how to populate your model if we can see details about what you want to accomplish, and what you are working from.

Comment: yeah - I tried that - unfortunately I can't post an image. I'll try editing my post with some more information

Comment: As I look more into this, it seems I need to (somehow) include my child table in my datacontext. qDB = new goalsDataClassesDataContext(); will allow me to access qDB.ilpActivities, but not any of the columns, such as qDB.ilpActivities.activityName;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you change:

```
public goals GetGoalActivities(int id) { return qDB.ilpActivities.Where(g => g.goalID == id); }
```

to:

```
public IEnumerable<ilpActivities> GetGoalActivities(int id) { return qDB.ilpActivities.Where(g => g.goalID == id); }
```

because `qDB.ilpActivities.Where(g => g.goalID == id);` returns an IEnumerable of activites, not a single goal like the previous method.

Comment: Would this require another model? I thought about an activities model but that made the ability to put the ilpActivities table in the goals model seem kinda pointless.

Comment: Placing the above in my goalsModel throws this: Error 1 The type or namespace name 'ilpActivities' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: They are on the same namespace as your datacontext

Comment: Sorry - then I'm missing something. My datacontext was generated for me. This is my first MVC project so it's quite possible I'm missing something obvious. In my dbml file the name is still ilpActivities .. yet I get that error (in my previous comment) when I attempt to reference it.

Comment: Reviewing my dbml I found ilpActivities is actually ilpActivity. Making that change the above seems to work. However, in my view I still have only the fields from goals available. How do I call this in my controller to pull the activities into my model?

Comment: Woohoo - it works. From here I just had to change the model on my view: @model ILP.Models.ilpActivity ... I decided to delete my partialview and recreate choosing ilpActivity as my model so I could get the scaffolding. Wow... it appears to work - thanks for getting me pointed in the right direction!

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if the method I am posting is Linq or not but I use this all the time with Entity Framework for my data connection.

First of all in your data model you should create an association between the two tables, when you have created the association you can now include data from both tables easily.

```
// Include Activities 
public IEnumerable<Goal> GetGoalActivities (int GoalId) {
    qDB.Goal.Include("Activities").Where(w => w.goal_id == GoalId);
}
```

Comment: That looks like my formatting - which I assumed was linq??? - unfortunately in this case the "include" throws an error (I changed Goal to goals): Error 1 'System.Data.Linq.Table<ILP.Models.goals>' does not contain a definition for 'Include' and no extension method 'Include' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Data.Linq.Table<ILP.Models.goals>' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: Did you set up an association and navigation in the entity framework model?   If you want to be able to include entities I think you need to have one or both set up.  Then you can use the model name in the include or the navigation property name.

Comment: Could you elaborate? What do I need to put where to use ".Include" ? Sorry - I'm new to this